# What's the difference between supervenience and reduction?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, physicalism, reductionism

From IEP, supervenience is defined as follows: F, supervenes on a class of properties, G, just in case there is no difference in F-properties without some difference in G-properties.

My question is, what is the difference between F supervening on G and F being reducible to G? Let us try substituting F for "mind" and G for "brain". This means there is no mental difference without some difference in the brain. But doesn't this imply that the brain determines every thought in the mind? And if so, doesn't this imply some kind of reductive materialism regarding the mind?

Comment: "*Supervenience inherits the metaphysical spirit of reductionism. According to supervenience theses, the microscopic determines the macroscopic, at least in the sense of providing a sufficient condition for any
macroscopic property. Thus if this dependency is not to be wholly mysterious, there is presumably some set of facts that could be known that would permit the inference of the macroscopic from a sufficient knowledge of the microscopic. Perhaps we could not, even in principle, know these facts. But God, I suppose, would
need merely to exist in order to know them*", Dupre.

Comment: His [Metaphysical Disorder and Scientific Disunity](https://classes.matthewjbrown.net/teaching-files/hps/dupre.pdf) is generally an illuminating read. For the more "official" compare-and-contrast see [SEP, Supervenience and Reduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/supervenience/#SupeRedu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Supervenience* and *reduction* are terms of art in philosophy that denote two dependence relations. We use the notion of supervenience often to describe a relationship between two sets of properties or features: When we say that **F** supervenes on **G**, we point out that any difference in **F**-properties implies a difference in **G**-properties.

Schematically speaking, **F** supervenes on **G** if, for every possible case, the truth value of a proposition about **F** is determined by the truth value of the corresponding proposition(s) about **G** (and *vice versa*, depending on the specific relationship). This should not imply that there is a causal relation between **G** and **F**, but rather that **F**'s existence or nature necessarily depends on **G**'s.

On the other side, we say that **F** is reducible to **G** if **F** can be fully explained in terms of **G** or the properties in **F** can be fully derived from the properties in **G**. Therefore, understanding **G** is sufficient to understand **F** entirely, rendering an appeal to any other information or concepts redundant. In some contexts, **F** can be said to be simply a "higher-level" way of describing or interpreting **G**.

By extension, we can use these ideas to talk about some other items of philosophical discourse (concepts, phenomena, etc.)

A crucial point is that supervenience does not necessarily imply reducibility; there are cases that, while changes in **F**-properties are dependent on changes in **G**-properties, we cannot give an account of **F**-properties solely by **G**-properties. The key idea here is that there may be [emergent properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties-emergent/) in **F** that are not determined by the underlying **G**-properties in the strict sense.
Emergence refers to the phenomenon where complex systems display properties that cannot be explained by examining their individual components. Imagine **F** as a new property arising from the complex interplay of **G** and other factors. While **F** depends (supervenes) on **G** , it cannot be simply analysed away by (reduced to) **G** alone, because **F** introduces something new and distinct, even though it is rooted or grounded in **G**.

We may see clear instances of that in biological explanations; for example, photosynthesis emerges from the underlying chemical reactions in plants. While it depends on those chemical reactions, it involves additional levels of complexity and organisation that cannot be reduced to just them.

However, our involvement with supervenience and reduction cannot be taken in a simple way. When **F** is not only supervenient on **G**, but also completely reducible to **G**, a talk of **F** might *prima facie* seem redundant, but even in such cases, there may still be value and utility in discussing **F**-properties for various reasons, like providing different perspectives, enhancing practical applications, tailoring communication, and opening up insights into the underlying mechanisms, enabling better understanding of certain aspects of the system.

In scientific research, multiple levels of explanation are often used depending on the context and the goals. The choice between using **F** or **G** might be guided by factors such as simplicity, explanatory power, and the ability to make predictions. There may be benefits of seeing in a reductionist perspective, such as the following (it should be remarked that these are not mutually exclusive, more than one of them can be associated with a concrete case):

**Different perspectives and levels of abstraction.** **F** and **G** might represent different perspectives or levels of abstraction for understanding the same phenomenon. **G** might be the fundamental, underlying mechanism, while **F** is a higher-level description or interpretation of **G** that's more relevant or appropriate for certain contexts or applications.

For example, in biology, we might discuss complex phenomena at the molecular level (reductionist approach) or at the organism level (holistic approach), depending on the specific questions or goals of the investigation.

Another example is the concept of temperature. In physics, temperature can be understood in terms of the average kinetic energy of the molecules in a system (**G**). However, we usually talk about temperature in terms of our sensory experience of hot and cold (**F**). Both **F** and **G** describe the same phenomenon, but from different perspectives and levels of abstraction.

**Practicality and Efficiency.** While **G** might be the fundamental explanation, it might be more practical, efficient, or feasible in certain situations to work directly with higher-level concepts like **F**, for **F** might lead to simpler calculations, quicker inferences, or more intuitive understanding.

Specifically, in engineering, we often use simplified models of complex systems based on their behaviour (**F**) rather than delving into the intricate underlying mechanisms (**G**). This allows for quicker design iterations and more efficient optimisation.

**Explanatory Convenience.** It might be more convenient or practical to discuss and work with **F**-properties in certain contexts. It might be easier to communicate certain phenomena using the language of **F**, even if ultimately those phenomena can be explained in terms of **G**.

Consider a physician explaining pain to a patient in terms of tissue damage and inflammation (**F**) rather than complex neurochemical processes (**G**). This simplifies the explanation and focuses on the relevant information for the patient's understanding and treatment.

**Heuristics and intuition.** While **G** represents the fundamental truth, **F** can be a valuable tool for navigating, applying, and interpreting that truth in different contexts and for different purposes. Reasoning by **F** can provide valuable heuristics and intuition for understanding and exploring **G** further. **F**'s higher-level perspective can offer insights into the behaviour and potential applications of **G**.

Arguably, the concept of natural selection (**F**) helps us explore the underlying mechanisms of evolution at the molecular level (**G**) and better predict how populations might adapt under different conditions.

A view that has garnered widespread support is that mind is an essential outcome of a supremely organised substance (conceived mainly as the organ of brain, but it can be plausibly argued that not limited to brain; see [embodied cognition thesis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/embodied-cognition/)). Subsequently, on this view, mental states (like pain) are often said to supervene on physical brain states. While pain depends on certain neural activity, it cannot be fully explained or reduced to just that activity. The subjective experience of pain is something emergent from the complex interplay of neurobiology and other factors. Also, mental properties (e.g., exhibiting consciousness or intentionality) are be said to supervene on physical properties (like neural states), but they are not reducible to them, even if it is admitted that there is a strong correlation between mental and physical states.

However, once [the principle of causal closure](https://iep.utm.edu/mind-and-the-causal-exclusion-problem/) is accepted, which is philosophically quite reasonable and scientifically indispensable, supervenience of mental states/properties are forced to be entirely accounted for by a reductive explanation in terms of physical states/properties alone. Thus, mind seems to arise *ex nihilo* and free will seems to be an "effect without cause." Note that this is not a recent issue; consider, for instance, Spinoza on the question of free will.

Nevertheless, this line of reasoning overlooks significant factors of approach to the nature of mind. To cite a few:

- Suppose **F** is supervenient on **G**. In one context/viewpoint, **F** may be irreducible to **G** whereas reducible in another context/viewpoint and still prove to be a useful term of discourse, as mentioned above.
- The notion of causality (as accepted in science, specifically in physics) is not exhaustive of all grounds of explanation and claims about being. There are non-causal relations besides it, which can be plausibly argued to be as basic as causal relations.
- It is unjustified to deem the non-causal relations as less fundamental in the absence of insufficient understanding of both causality and extra-causality, and further, their interactions.

A general methodological wisdom tells us that a main way to grapple with untenable conclusions is to refine and revise the premisses. We cannot further expand on the present question, but I think one of the premisses has already been given by Aristotle in a clear manner (*De Anima*, Book 3, Section 4):

> ὁ ἄρα καλούμενος τῆς ψυχῆς νοῦς (λέγω δὲ νοῦν ᾧ διανοεῖται καὶ
> ὑπολαμβάνει ἡ ψυχή) οὐθέν ἐστιν ἐνεργείᾳ τῶν ὄντων πρὶν νοεῖν·
>
> That part of the soul, then, which we call mind (by mind I mean that
> whereby the soul thinks and judges) has no actual existence [it is not
> a *thing*] until it thinks.

Comment: What's fascinating is that this takes a perspective of theoretical explanation that essentially highlights the isomorphic nature of the discourses and that both are subtended to a larger discourse framework.